# Adjusting how a ModelForm is displayed

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've made some changes to an admin form so that I could display a TextField like a CharField but the form itself looks pretty ugly in the admin menu as the form elements aren't stretching properly. I also don't want to display the name of model when I print it since it's already on the page. How would I make those changes? Ideally I would like the link field to take up all the remaining space shown the screenshot below.

`admin.py`

```
from linkrotator.models import Link, LinkList
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class LinkModelForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    link = forms.CharField( label = "Link")

    class Meta:
        model = Link

class LinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = LinkModelForm
    model = Link

class LinkListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ( LinkInline, )

admin.site.register(LinkList, LinkListAdmin)
```

How it looks.

[image: A picture from the admin interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the CSS for the admin section, easymode:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions